# printing reversed list of prime numbers with given interval

Tags: python

so I figured out how to print all the prime number in reversed form a given interval, but for a test case when they place the lower bound to 1, it will print it as well. As we know that 1 is not a prime number.

my code is:

```
def prime_list_reversed(x, y):
"""
Input: the number x and y
Output: all prime numbers within [x,y] in reverse order

>>> prime_list_reversed(3, 10)
[7, 5, 3]
>>> prime_list_reversed(3, 3)
[3]
>>> prime_list_reversed(2, 2)
[2]
"""
assert type(x) == int, "first argument must be an integer"
assert type(y) == int, "second argument must be an integer"
assert x > 1, "1 is not a prime number"
assert y >= x,  "second argument must be >= the first one"

# YOUR CODE IS HERE #
lst = []
for i in range(x, y + 1):
    for c in range(2, i):
        if (i % c) == 0:
            break
    else:
        lst.append(i)
return list(reversed(lst))
```

one test case

```
prime_list_reversed(1, 3)
[3,2,1]
```

Comment: What do you think `range(2, 1)` will return?

Comment: i could always assert that the user has to pick a number greater than 1, but that i think it would be better if they can use the lower bound greater than 0

Comment: `range(2, 1)` is *empty* since the upper bound is smaller than the lower bound, hence you never perform any checks. *All* numbers between `1` and `3` (or any other range) will be emitted.

Comment: range(2,1 ) will return nothing

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem "All numbers between 1 and 3 (or any other range) will be emitted." Do you mean "omitted"?

Comment: @Errick-MichaleSantos: no, it is a generator, but it will never *yield* something. But regarless: if `range(2, 1)` is `None`, then why do you think your `for c in range(2, 1)` will filter out any number?

Comment: @Acccumulation: no *emitted* (in functional programming the term *emitted* means that it generates that item in the list).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Your comment makes it sound like `range(2,1)` will emit all numbers between `1` and `3`. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @willemVanOnsem oh, so then when one is place into the lower bound it will basically yield (for c in range (2,1)) 1 being i

Comment: @Acccumulation: nooo... There are *two* ranges here: the range of the elements over which we consider numbers, and the `range(..)` that is used to *check* if it is a prime number. Somehow you emit a lot of confusion, omitting any reasoning :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem "will be emitted" is the passive voice, which is a grammatical form in which one can omit the subject. By doing so, one often, as you did in this case, generates confusion. By avoiding saying *what* emit the numbers, and having `range(2,1)` the only candidate mentioned in your comment, you implied that `range(2,1)` was the intended subject. It would have been much clearer to say "The function will emit all of the numbers". Or, even better, "The function will return a list containing all of the numbers".

Comment: In fact, if you had just said "returned", rather than "emitted", the subject would have been clear. All statements emit results, but only functions return, so why go out your way to find a word that is overbroad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prime checker will for `i=1` construct the `range(2, 1)`, but that range is *empty*. Indeed:

```
>>> list(range(2, 1))
[]
```

So that means *no* checking is done for `i=1`, and hence your program considers it to be a *prime* number. There are two things that we can do here:

1. check with the `if` statement that `i == 1` to avoid emitting;
2. ensuring that the outer range can never emit `1` in the first place.

```
def prime_list_reversed(x, y):
    # ...
    lst = []
    for i in range(max(2, x), y + 1):
        for c in range(2, i):
            if (i % c) == 0:
                break
        else:
            lst.append(i)
    return list(reversed(lst))
```

The above solves the problem, but it is not very elegantly: we first construct a list, and then reverse the list. We can simply emit elements in reverse as well:

```
def prime_list_reversed(x, y):
    # ...
    lst = []
    for i in range(y, max(2, x) - 1, -1):
        for c in range(2, i):
            if (i % c) == 0:
                break
        else:
            lst.append(i)
    return lst
```

Now we thus yield elements in reverse. But still the code is inefficient: we test all even numbers. But it is sufficient to test if a number can be divided by `2`, if not, we can omit check for `4`, `6`, etc. since if it is not divisable by `2`, it definitely is *not* divisable by `4`, `6`. Instead of checking if a number is divisable by `2`

```
def prime_list_reversed(x, y):
    # ...
    lst = []
    for i in range(y - (~y & 1), max(3, x) - 1, -2):
        for c in range(3, i, 2):
            if (i % c) == 0:
                break
        else:
            lst.append(i)
    if x <= 2 < y:
        lst.append(2)
    return lst
```

But still it can more efficient. If a number *a* is divisable by *b*, we know that there is a *c = a/b*. This means that if *b >√a*, then *c≤√a*. We can exploit this property: it is sufficient to check up to *√i*, since we know that otherwise we have tested it through the other division:

```
from math import ceil, sqrt

def prime_list_reversed(x, y):
    # ...
    lst = []
    for i in range(y - (~y & 1), max(3, x) - 1, -2):
        for c in range(3, ceil(sqrt(i))+1, 2):
            if not i % c:
                break
        else:
            lst.append(i)
    if x <= 2 < y:
        lst.append(2)
    return lst
```

Finally it is usually better to make this a generator, since this allows us to *lazily* for example take the first 10 elements:

```
from math import ceil, sqrt

def prime_list_reversed(x, y):
    # ...
    for i in range(y - (~y & 1), max(3, x) - 1, -2):
        for c in range(3, ceil(sqrt(i))+1, 2):
            if not i % c:
                break
        else:
            yield i
    if x <= 2 < y:
        yield 2
```

we then obtain as for the range between `1` and `500`:

```
>>> list(prime_list_reversed(1, 500))
[499, 491, 487, 479, 467, 463, 461, 457, 449, 443, 439, 433, 431, 421, 419, 409, 401, 397, 389, 383, 379, 373, 367, 359, 353, 349, 347, 337, 331, 317, 313, 311, 307, 293, 283, 281, 277, 271, 269, 263, 257, 251, 241, 239, 233, 229, 227, 223, 211, 199, 197, 193, 191, 181, 179, 173, 167, 163, 157, 151, 149, 139, 137, 131, 127, 113, 109, 107, 103, 101, 97, 89, 83, 79, 73, 71, 67, 61, 59, 53, 47, 43, 41, 37, 31, 29, 23, 19, 17, 13, 11, 7, 5, 3, 2]
```